# PartialFunction and MatchError

Tags: scala, partialfunction

There are two ways to define PF: 1) with literal `case {}` syntax and 2) as explicit class. I need the following function throw a MatchError, but in the second case that doesn't happen.

1) with case

```
val test: PartialFunction[Int, String] =  {
  case x if x > 100 => x.toString
}
```

2) as class

```
val test = new PartialFunction[Int, String] {
  def isDefinedAt(x: Int) = x > 100
  def apply(x: Int) = x.toString
}
```

Should i, in the seconds case, manually call `isDefinedAt`, shouldn't it be called implicitly by the compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to call `isDefinedAt` manually in your `apply` method:

```
val test = new PartialFunction[Int, String] {
  def isDefinedAt(x: Int) = x > 100
  def apply(x: Int) = if(isDefinedAt(x)) x.toString else throw new MatchError(x)
}
```

If you want to avoid this code, you can simply use the first way to define your partial function. It is syntactic sugar and will result in a valid definition of both `isDefinedAt` and `apply`. As described in the [Scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf), your first definition will expand to the following:

```
val test = new scala.PartialFunction[Int, String] {
  def apply(x: Int): String = x match {
    case x if x > 100 => x.toString
  }
  def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean = {
    case case x if x > 100 => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isDefinedAt` is not a guard: it is not checked whenever you call the `PartialFunction`.

In your first case, the `MatchError`occurs because of the pattern matching failure. Actually, you can find out how the `Partialfunction` is built in the first case in the §8.5 of the [Scala Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

In the second case, apply is defined for all `x` and then your definition of `isDefinedAt` is not valid.