# Scala PartialFunctions giving match error: weird behavior

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use a partial function for some validations, lets take an example of a string:

```
def isLengthValid: PartialFunction[String, Option[String]] ={
  case s:String if s.length > 5 => Some("Invalid")
}

def isStringValid: PartialFunction[String, Option[String]] ={
  case s: String if s == "valid" => Some("Valid")
}

isLengthValid("valid") orElse isStringValid("valid")
```

> expected output => Some("Valid")

But I'm getting a match Error:

> scala.MatchError: valid (of class java.lang.String)

Could anyone help that what is going wrong here, because as per my understanding **.isDefinedAt** is called internally and is should not give **matchError**.

P.S ignore the inputs, this is just an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong. The [ScalaDocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html) clearly states, "It is the responsibility of the caller to call `isDefinedAt` before calling `apply` ...".

Your code isn't calling `isDefinedAt`, which is causing the exception, so you have to explicitly call it or you can employ other methods that hide the `isDefinedAt` internally.

```
Seq("valid") collect (isLengthValid orElse isStringValid)
//res0: Seq[Option[String]] = List(Some(Valid))

Seq("vlad") collect (isLengthValid orElse isStringValid)
//res1: Seq[Option[String]] = List()
```

Answer (score 4):

This works as intended if you write the last line as

```
(isLengthValid orElse isStringValid)("valid")
```

I suspect the problem is that your version desugars to
`(isLengthValid.apply("valid")).orElse(isStringValid.apply("valid"))`

This means the `apply` is calculated before the `orElse` takes place, which means the partial function is treated as a total function and a match error is thrown as Valy Dia's answer explains. The `orElse` is actually being called on the result output, not the partial function.

Comment: Thanks this works, and this was what was i was looking for

Comment: @geek94; Really? This is what you were looking for? But this still throws a `matchError` when you try to validate a string like `"vld"`. That's dangerous code.

Answer (score 2):

The error message comes from the first expression - `isLengthValid`.

It is define only for `string` with a length stricly greater than 5. Hence when it is applied to a the string `"valid"` of length 5, it throws a `MatchError`:

```scala
scala>"valid".length
res5: Int = 5

isLengthValid("valid")
scala.MatchError: valid (of class java.lang.String)
```

If the method `isLengthValid` defined this way instead (**Note** the greater than equal sign), it wouldn't throw the `MatchError` :

```scala
def isLengthValid: PartialFunction[String, Option[String]] ={
  case s:String if s.length >= 5 => Some("Invalid")
}

scala>isLengthValid("valid")
res8: Option[String] = Some("Invalid")
```

And the original expression would return an `Option`:

```scala
scala>isLengthValid("valid") orElse isStringValid("valid")
res9: Option[String] = Some("Invalid")
```

What you could do here as well as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806246/partialfunction-and-matcherror), is to use this definition instead:

```scala
val isLengthValid = new PartialFunction[String, Option[String]] {
  def isDefinedAt(x: String) = x.length > 5
  def apply(x: String) = Some("Invalid")
}

scala>isLengthValid("valid")
res13: Some[String] = Some("Invalid")
```